# How long has Pod::Usage been in Core?

Tags: perl

I'm working on a Centos box that contains Perl 5.10.1.  However for some reason it is missing [`Pod::Usage`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Pod/Usage.html).

Is there a way to determine how long `Pod::Usage` has been part of core without scanning through all the Perl version deltas?

Comment: `corelist Pod::Usage` says "Pod::Usage was first released with perl v5.6.0"

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Ty, I didn't know about that utility.

Comment: yw. Now I'm curious what's wrong with your install...

Comment: I'm curious too.  For some reason the system perl is just missing some core libraries.  Was missing Time::Piece as well.  Unfortunately, investigating the cause is a low priority, as just making sure that the module is deployed to all environments is the most important thing.  If I ever figure it out though, I'll chime back here :)

Comment: I believe redhat has split up the perl "core" into multiple rpms, not all of which are necessarily there.  Try installing the perl-core rpm, "a metapackage which requires all of the perl bits and modules in the upstream tarball from perl.org."

Comment: [This blog post](http://perlhacks.com/2012/08/a-cautionary-tale/) explains what is going on.